# Problem in Displaying image Using RestApi

Tags: apex, rest-api, webservices

Am unable to display image which is there in external site .When am Displaying am getting like this

```
core.filemanager.FileBlobValue@4747ae4b
```

here is my code

```
public class RestImage {

public blob image {get;set;}


public string code {get;set;}

public string values {get;set;}
public void myConnection(){

s= new SampleLead__c();
http p =new http();

httprequest req= new httprequest();

req.setEndpoint('http://1.cuzillion.com/bin/resource.cgi?sleep=10');
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setTimeout(11000);
httpresponse res= p.send(req);
code=res.getStatus();
values=res.getBody();
image=res.getBodyAsBlob();

}
}
```

her is my VisualForce page

```
<apex:page controller="RestImage" action="{!myConnection}">
  {!code}{!values}
  <apex:form >

  {!image}</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inline the Data URI scheme:

Amend your **Apex** class with the following:

```
public blob image {get;set;}
...
public void myConnection(){
    ...
    image=EncodingUtil.base64encode(res.getBodyAsBlob());
}
```

Then update your **Visualforce** page:

```
<apex:image value="data:image/gif;base64,{!Image}" />
```

Interesting that you are stalling runtime using a sleepy URL ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a img tag setting the src to the external site?

```
<img src="http://1.cuzillion.com/bin/resource.cgi?sleep=10" />
```

*I've noticed that you are trying to test something about loading performance, isn't? remember the browser load the img contents in an async way.*

Comment: yes @marting then how can i show image ? is there any possible solution for that ,,instead of going for image tag ,how come i show those image

Comment: I think that I cant understand what are you trying to do. The result of VF is always HTML, the way to show an image in HTML is using `<img>`. Whay you can't use it tag?

Comment: A hybrid-solution would be to (1) use the img tag as suggested, but (2) load the image via jQuery (or any Javascript that'll work)instead of in the controller

Comment: or (3) write a @RemoteAction Apex Method that writes the URL for you (in case you wanted it automated using SF data)